# new char error C (new undeclared)

Tags: c, char

I do not know why the new is giving me an error. This is the code. Thank you for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float promedio(int x[], int nValores);

int main(){

   FILE *bin, *archivoSalida;

   char *entrada, *salida;
   int num;
   int contador = 0;
   int nValores=10000;



   entrada = new char[50];
   salida = new char[50];
```

Comment: Because there is no `new` in c.

Comment: simply because new is not C.

Comment: How can I define the size of those char variables then?

Comment: Do you have a C textbook? If you don't, get one.

Comment: for dynamic memory allocation, use `malloc` or `calloc`; but you could also write `char entrada[50]`

Comment: The `new` memory allocation operator is found in C++, not in C.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `new` in C.

Try: `char entrada[50], salida[50];`

For better readability try:

```
char entrada[50] = { 0 };
char salida[50]  = { 0 };
```